# Yahoo Finanace API for Currency Exchange

Tags: yahoo, currency, yql, yahoo-finance

I am trying to create a simple app in Android. The application will take as input all the live currencies I can query from Yahoo, I am using YQL(Yahoo Query Language) to get the these.

When I use (from the YQL console):

```
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("USDINR")
```

I am getting the USD-INR exchange Rate and when I use the query:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair="USDINR, EURUSD,CADUSD,GBPUSD"
```

I am getting currency exchanges of USD, INR, EUR, CAD and GBP.

How can I get all the currencies(160 in total), using the Select statement, without hard coding the Currency Codes in YQL? or Is there any other way of getting all the currencies from Yahoo ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can not, at each layer the value pairs are expected.
the YQL request against the table calls the service

http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=....

which in turn requires the query to be specific

https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.xchange.xml